# Programmatically created iFrame is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I'm using a short bit of C# code  to create an `iFrame` with a pdf inside of it.

However, the iFrame comes up empty.

```
 LiteralControl c= new  LiteralControl("<iframe id='embeddedFrame' name='embeddedFrame' runat=server src="+filePath+" width=400 height=400></iframe>");
 ph.Controls.Add(c);
```

Viewing the page source gives me this:

```
<iframe id="embeddedFrame" name="embeddedFrame" runat="server" src="C:\Users\Houseman\Desktop\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Data\Untitled1.pdf" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

Which looks correct. I do indeed have that .pdf file in that location. There's no 404 error, it's just blank...

What am I doing wrong, or how could I fix this?

---

I can access the file through my browser, except that I have to take out `localhost:8683` and replace it with `file:///`

---

I'm accessing the file with

```
string PdfLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("Data") ,pdfn);
```

Where `pdfn` is the filename of the upload +".pdf"

Comment: I would suspect this is an absolute vs relative link issue. If you are trying to view this in a browser, files linked from the hard disk are blocked by default for security. How you are testing this - remotely, or locally?

Comment: I'm testing this locally, using the asp.net development server that starts when you push the "play" button in Visual Studio

Comment: Can you try putting the PDF file in whatever folder VS uses when executing this and change the link so it doesn't include the C:/? It might be you application's folder, but not sure. Can you try uploading the file and then using it's http:// link to test if it works? If it does, you know it is a problem with your path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
string PDFLocation = "~/Data/" + pdfn;
```

You're getting the absolute server file path, which isn't accessible from the browser. You need the website-relative path instead.

You'll need to combine this answer with Yuriy's answer about creating the iframe as a server control.

Comment: Now I get a 404 from `Requested URL: /~/Data/Untitled1.pdf`. Except that I don't actually type that first `/` in there, it just appears

Comment: Where is your data folder is located? Is it accessible via HTTP url?. Apparently it is a path issue and IFRAME cannot load a file:// source

Comment: my Data is at `WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Data` Relative to the code, it's in the same directory. The code is also in `WebApplication1\WebApplication1`

Comment: I changed `~` to a `.` and it worked. Just a hunch based on how certain shells navigate paths. Hopefully when I put this on a server it uses the same standards...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating literal (and btw, you cannot create `runat="sever` controls these way) try creating actual IFRAME control:

```
HtmlGenericControl c = new HtmlGenericControl();

c.TagName = "IFRAME";
c.Attributes["src"] = filePath;
c.Attributes["id"] = "embeddedFrame";
c.Attributes["name"] = "embeddedFrame";
c.Attributes["width"] = "400";
c.Attributes["height"] = "400";

ph.Controls.Add(c);
```

And make sure that the path is available from your browser, not only from the server.

Comment: That gives me the same results. But I have new information about the file path. I'll edit my question to include it. Yes, the path is available from my browser, but I have to replace `localhost` with `file`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What happens if instead of `filePath` as a test you would assign a literal path that you *can* see in browser?

Comment: The same thing. I assigned `file:///C:/Users/Houseman/Desktop/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/Data/Untitled1.pdf` and it came up blank. If I put that same path into a browser, it'd take me right to it.